# trying to assign a key binding for a simple c# app in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to simply assign an unused keybinding ctrl-alt-8 for running even an internal command such as "Open", but I get the message "Word cannot change the function of the specified key".

I am using:

```
Application.KeyBindings.Add(Word.WdKeyCategory.wdKeyCategoryCommand, "Open", Application.BuildKeyCode(Word.WdKey.wdKeyControl, Word.WdKey.wdKeyAlt, Word.WdKey.wdKey8));
```

Comment: Which version of Word is involved?

Comment: I am using MS Word 2016

Comment: command is `"FileOpen"`

Comment: Windows or Mac? Mac version cannot perform Key Bindings.

Comment: The thing is i'm trying by this key combo to call a form in the addin, not necessarily call the open command in word. I appreciate the  answer tough @Slai. It's Windows.

Comment: If you are able to do it manually, I recommend trying Record Macro to check the generated code.